# How to specify the Id in LabelFor Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have LabelFor in Mvc like

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
```

To create custom LableFor to give title and so on.. i have created my own like

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string Title = null)
```

To give title i am calling

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeAdress,"This is Employee ADress")
```

Now that correct and working fine

Now at 500 to 600  places i have taken like this

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
```

I don't want to hardcode title here like

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName,"EmployeeName")
```

I wants that whenever it finds this

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
```

then my custom method should call i.e
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor(this HtmlHelper html, Expression> expression, string Title = null)

so that i don't need to change in whole application but its calling default Mvc method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LabelFor()` is an extension method (static) and therefore cannot be overridden. You have to create your own Html Helper Extension method to achieve what you require. Rename your custom label htmlhelper to `LabelForCustom` (or whatever name you'd use) and replace all `@Html.LabelFor(...)` with this new extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DisplayAttribute` or `DisplayNameAttribute` for this purpose. [See this link about DisplayAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)